# Intersection of closed balls

Tags: metric-spaces

How does one find a decreasing sequence of closed balls ( not necessarily concentric) in a complete metric space whose intersection is empty?

Comment: what do you mean "find"? do you just want one example?

Comment: Another example in an answer to [An Example of a Nested Decreasing Sequence of Bounded Closed Sets with Empty Intersection](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1397739)

Comment: I am looking for a complete metric space and the radii of the closed balls may not decrease to zero. I don't see any such example in above posts. By 'find' I mean given an example. Apparently one can construct a metric on the natural numbers for which {n,n+1,n+2,...} is a closed ball for each n and the metric is complete.