# Modulus of continuity of bounding a metric

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

It is well-known that every metric space $(X,d)$ is *homeomorphic* to a bounded metric space $(X,\bar{d})$ where:
$$
\bar{d}:X^2\ni (x_1,x_2)\mapsto \frac{d(x_1,x_2)}{1+d(x_1,x_2)} \in [0,1];
$$
(see [this post for instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156318/proof-that-every-metric-space-is-homeomorphic-to-a-bounded-metric-space)).
Is the *homeomorphism*
$$
h:(X,d)\ni x \mapsto x \in (X,\bar{d}),
$$ ever *uniformly continuous?* and, if so, how does its modulus of continuity relate to $X$'s diameter?

I anticipate that the map is only uniformly continuous if the diameter of $(X,d)$; by which I mean, $\operatorname{diam}(X,d):=\sup_{x_1,x_2\in X}\, d(x_1,x_2)$), is finite.

Comment: Diameter depends on the metric you consider, and "the diameter of $X$" is not well-defined as it is stated

Comment: @Didier He means (I think) the diameter wrt the original $d$ I think, as the new metric almost surely has diameter $1$ now. And by the homeomorphism he means the identity function $h(x)=x$ I suppose.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Exactly; but I'll make the edits to clarify. (Also *she ;))

Comment: I just assumed “Tom” is a he by default. Thomas etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh no worries; now I see why totally fair :)  Sorry about the mix up on my end :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean is that both metrics induce the same topology on $X$. In other words, as Henno Brandsma comments, that $id : (X,d) \to (X,\bar d)$ is a homeomorphism. Of course $id$ is uniformly continuous. We have
$$\bar d(x_1,x_2) \le d(x_1,x_2)$$
because $1  + d(x_1,x_2) \ge 1$.

However, we cannot expect that $id : (X,\bar d) \to (X, d)$ is always uniformly continuous. But it is if $\delta = \text{diam}_d(X) < \infty$. In that case we have

$$d(x_1,x_2)  = (1 +\delta) \frac{d(x_1,x_2)}{1 + \delta} \le (1 +\delta)  \frac{d(x_1,x_2)}{1 + d(x_1,x_2)} = (1 +\delta)\bar d(x_1,x_2) .$$